# how to keep the leading 0 in Python

Tags: python

I'm extracting one number from an XLS file :

```
var = workBook.sheet_by_index(3).cell_value(4,1)
var = 0136 
type(var) = float
```

when I'm trying to print the var i got always different results :

```
print(int(var)) = 136
print(str(var)) = 136.0
```

I don’t find a simple way to simply print out : 0136

Comment: I would suggest print it as a `string`.

Comment: What library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting

```
print('{:04d}'.format(136))
# Returns 0136
```

In your case:

```
var = 136 
print('{:04d}'.format(var))
# Returns: 0136
```